# PHP - Wait for file to exist

Tags: php, while-loop, wait

I wanted to exec a exe which generates txt files and also in another script then check that the txt files have been created.

In xampp i am simply dragging in a test.txt file to the following php scripts dir but it doesn't seem to work correctly, also if i add in text.txt to the dir and start the script rather than starting before it is added then the second echo never seems to happen.

How can i make PHP Wait for the text file to exist and then continue?

```
set_time_limit(0);

echo "Script began: " . date("d-m-Y h:i:s") . "<br>";

$status = file_exists("test.txt");
while($status != true) {
    if ($status == true) {
        echo "The file was found: " . date("d-m-Y h:i:s") . "<br>";
        break;
    }
}
```

This also does not work:

```
set_time_limit(0);

echo "Script began: " . date("d-m-Y h:i:s") . "<br>";

while(!file_exists("test.txt")) {
    if (file_exists("test.txt")) {
        echo "The file was found: " . date("d-m-Y h:i:s") . "<br>";
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: `$status` __never__ changes its value.

Comment: *"While status is not true, if status is true…"* – there's a lot wrong with this attempted logic.

Comment: i had tried changing it to be direct, see my edit but it still doesn't work, the second echo never happens also.

Comment: Your second attempt is better, but *"while not exists, if exists"* still makes no sense. That second piece at least *leaves the loop* when the file exists, contrary to the first version.

Comment: if it's while(file_exists("test.txt") then the echo runs as expected but it doesn't wait like needed. Usually i don't do this type of thing so im a bit confused as to what else might work.

Comment: Second code works fine.

Comment: what's the problem with your second code?

Comment: It doesn't exit the loop in xampp when the txt file gets added to the dir.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

this should works fine

```
set_time_limit(0);

echo "Script began: " . date("d-m-Y h:i:s") . "<br>";

do {
    if (file_exists("test.txt")) {
        echo "The file was found: " . date("d-m-Y h:i:s") . "<br>";
        break;
    }
} while(true);
```

Comment: if you were to add in a sleep(1); that would be directly after the if statement right?

Answer (score 6):

I trust that you have other safeguards in place to make sure that you’re not in an infinite loop.

```
while(!file_exists('test.txt'));
echo "The file was found: " . date("d-m-Y h:i:s") . "<br>";
```

would be simpler.

Anyway, your problem is with your pretest. Since it fails to begin with, it never repeats. What you need is a post test:

```
do {
    if (file_exists("test.txt")) {
        echo "The file was found: " . date("d-m-Y h:i:s") . "<br>";
        break;
    }
} while(!file_exists("test.txt"));
```

Comment: Thanks, i don't usually use while loops so i will make a note of this.

Comment: Do some sleeps, for gods sake :)

Answer (score 3):

I suppose you should use this approach:

```
set_time_limit(0);

echo "Script began: " . date("d-m-Y h:i:s") . "<br>";

while (true) {
    // we will always check for file existence at least one time
    // so if `test.txt` already exists - you will see the message
    // if not - script will wait until file appears in a folder
    if (file_exists("test.txt")) {
        echo "The file was found: " . date("d-m-Y h:i:s") . "<br>";
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Brief experiments suggest that waiting for an asynchronous file system change (using PHP as a module in Apache) must yield control in the loop. Otherwise, the number of loops spent waiting (such as for a file to be deleted by unlink()) seems to be random over a very large range. Yielding inside such a loop can be done by "usleep(250000)", which will yield control for 1/4 of a second.